# How to plot simple moving averages with stock data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to plot simple moving averages (SMA) using Apple's stock price. I have lines below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='darkgrid', context='talk', palette='Dark2')

my_year_month_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%y')

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\AAPL.csv')

# tried to change the Date format, then its 'start_date' and 'end_date' but it doesn't work 
# data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

short_rolling = data.rolling(window=20).mean()
long_rolling = data.rolling(window=100).mean()

start_date = '1/4/2010'
end_date = '12/31/2019'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

ax.plot(data.loc[start_date:end_date, :].index, data.loc[start_date:end_date, 'Close'], label='Price')
ax.plot(long_rolling.loc[start_date:end_date, :].index, long_rolling.loc[start_date:end_date, 'Close'], label = '100-days SMA')
ax.plot(short_rolling.loc[start_date:end_date, :].index, short_rolling.loc[start_date:end_date, 'Close'], label = '20-days SMA')

ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_ylabel('Price in $')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_year_month_fmt)

plt.show()
```

But the plotting isn't successful.

[image]

What did I do wrong, and how I can correct it?

[image]

Comment: I don't get the plot output that you get.  I think you may need to change the statement `data = pd.read_csv('C:\\AAPL.csv')` because this alone does not set the index for `data`.  Can you provide the exact code that created your plot?

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question to something related to the problem (which is not the rolling averages).  E.g. 'Why is selected data range from Pandas DataFrame not appearing in plot?'

Comment: Note to readers: this post featured a link to a CSV file, but it was removed as the file had disappeared (for a second time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted, it seems as though you didn't set the index of the dataframe after loading the data from the csv file.  `pd.read_csv` does not by default assume the first column is the index.

If you had tried `data.head()` you would have noticed that Pandas adds a default index:

```
         Date  Open  High   Low  Close     Volume Currency
0  2010-01-04  7.62  7.66  7.58   7.64  493728704      USD
1  2010-01-05  7.66  7.70  7.62   7.66  601904640      USD
2  2010-01-06  7.66  7.69  7.53   7.53  552158912      USD
3  2010-01-07  7.56  7.57  7.47   7.52  477129760      USD
4  2010-01-08  7.51  7.57  7.47   7.57  447876768      USD
```

Thus, none of the subsequent `df.loc` methods found any data that matched the dates you provide as strings.

The following worked for me.

I replaced the line

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\AAPL.csv')
```

with

```
data = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data = data.set_index('Date')
```

and this is the output I get:

[image]

Comment: superb! thank you for your help and knowledge sharing!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is the start_ end_date you provided is in str form. Maybe you can try to convert it to datetime format.

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date , '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Similarly, I will recommend that you standardize the data 'Date' column with

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. `df.loc` can accept dates in string format.